# How can I retrieve the attribute of a clicked element with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, jquery-selectors

I'm using wordpress and woocommerce, and I want to add some scripts to run when a product variation is selected, with jQuery.

I have a set of "buttons" in html like this:

```
<div class="adsw-attribute-option">
  <span class="meta-item-text sku-set" data-value="s">S</span>
  <span class="meta-item-text sku-set" data-value="m">M</span>
  <span class="meta-item-text sku-set" data-value="l">L</span>
  <span class="meta-item-text sku-set" data-value="xl">XL</span>
  <span class="meta-item-text sku-set" data-value="xxl">XXL</span>
  <span class="meta-item-text sku-set" data-value="xxxl">XXXL</span>
</div>
```

I add click listeners with the following:

```
$(".adsw-attribute-option > .meta-item-text").on("click", () => {})
```

And inside the handler I need to read the `data-value` attribute of the "button" that was clicked. First I tried: `$(this).attr("data-value")`. This returned `undefined`. I've tried with `.data` instead of the attr function, with the same result.

It seems like there's some issue with the usage of `$(this)`, I couldn't read any of its properties like html, or class.

I thought `$(this)` should refer to the object, that the event was called on, but it seems, this is not the case.

What am I missing here? Is there any other way to retrieve the value of "data-value" in this case?

Comment: Love when people reinvent radio buttons.

Comment: Because when you use an arrow function, `this` is going to not be what you clicked.

Comment: @epascarello this is generated by a plugin, no control over that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the .attr function:

```js
$(".adsw-attribute-option > .meta-item-text").on("click", function () {
  $(this).attr('data-value');
});
```

It's important you don't use an arrow function because you can't call this when using an arrow function.

Answer (score 1):

if you're using an arrow function for the handler, try using the function keyword instead. the arrow function will have the same `this` value as its parent context, so it won't give you access to the attribute you're trying to read.

```
$(".adsw-attribute-option > .meta-item-text").on("click", function(e) {
    console.log($(this).attr('data-value'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".adsw-attribute-option > .meta-item-text").on("click", e => {
  console.log($(e.target).data('value'));
  console.log(e.target.dataset.value);
});
```

You can use an arrow function, if you use the event passed in.